# Delete all Rows from a point in each sheet

Tags: vba

I'm trying to search for the last used row in column A, which I have managed to do fine, but when I try to use that to delete all rows under it, I keep getting an "Object Required" error. Any ideas?

I've researched a bit about For each xyz loops, but I can't get my head around it well enough to make it work.

```
Sub Range_End_Method()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Dim lRow As Long
   lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each ws In ActiveBook

        ws.Rows(lRow & ":" & ws.Rows.Count).Delete

    Next ws
End Sub
```

My expectations would be for (assuming the last used row is 6), for everything in row 7 and down to be deleted from the sheet. I have managed to get as far as to get the right row, but can't get it to delete.

Comment: There is no such thing as `ActiveBook` -  do you mean `ActiveWorkbook`? Always use `Option Explicit` to avoid such errors.

Comment: Also, since your `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` isn't fully qualified it will take the value from the active sheet. You should refer the sheet you want to take the last row from.

Comment: Now I'm getting a "doesn't support this property or method" error.

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim lRow As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook
        
        lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        ws.Rows(lRow & ":" & ws.Rows.Count).Delete
        
    Next ws

Answer (score 0):

The `"Object Required"` error is due to a **typo** in your code. 
 
Just change `ActiveBook` with `ActiveWorkbook` and it will be gone.

The other error is because to cycle through every sheet in your Workbook, you need to use the `.Sheets` property.

This is the corrected code:

```
Sub Range_End_Method()

Dim ws As Worksheet

   Dim lRow As Long
   lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        ws.Rows(lRow & ":" & ws.Rows.Count).Delete

    Next ws
End Sub
```

> **Note**: To avoid misspelling variables, remember to use `Option Explicit` at the start of every Module.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

The above code will return the last row used which means any other cells below this in this column are blank.
I guess you don't need to delete blank rows.

Comment: I'd love for that to be true, but column A only has X amount of rows, but columns B and onwards have several thousand rows each, so I really would need to delete the surplus data